# modx wayfinder 3 level deep menu

Tags: html, css, modx, modx-revolution

How can I create 3-level deep menu in modx revolution using wayfinder? The styles should be:

[image]

but now I have only:

[image]

How could I do this 3-level menu? How do I assign different styles for each level?

Now my wayfinder is called like this:

```
      [[Wayfinder? &startId=`6` &level=`2` &where=`{"isfolder":"1"}` &activeParentRowTpl=`menuRow_active` &rowTpl=`menuRow` &outerTpl=`menuOuter` &innerTpl=`menuInner` &innerRowTpl=`menuInnerRow` &hideSubMenus=`true`]]
```

But how to make it 3-level deep and display only children for the 2nd parent?

Comment: maybe `&level=\`3\`` ?

Comment: @Vasis i try it, but then i get a little makup trouble: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59666091/gg.png

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Wayfinder (2.3.3) has the option of outputting a class for every depth. The &level parameter in the snippet call sets the maximum amount of levels to output.

`<li class="[[+wf.level]]">[[+wf.linktext]]</li>`

Will output something like

`<li class="level-1">Your link</li>`

Edit:
If you need to output submenus for only the second level, use a combination of `+wf.level` in the  `&parentRowTpl` chunk to disable/hide any underlying DOM on higher levels.
A `&parentRowTpl` could look like this:

`<li class="parent [[+wf.level]]">[[+wf.linktext]] [[+wf.wrapper]]</li>`

And then you could use css selectors like `.parent.level-1 .submenu { display: none; }`.

Comment: something like this i do tonight... just didn't post here, but ok, later will accept